# Kivy: Send Notification at certain time

Tags: android, python, time, notifications, kivy

I would like to send a notification at a certain time (That I can specify) that can send even when the app is not in use. I have seen a few examples of this, but not in kivy. If anyone could give me some example code of this (in python and kivy) that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To send Push Notifications (messages that show up even if you app is closed) you could use One Signal (https://onesignal.com/). I have a video demo-ing the proof of concept on an iPhone. I don't have the tutorial made yet, but it's in the works. There are instructions in the video description for you to take a stab yourself. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7401ce1YcwM

Comment: Will this also work on android?

Comment: Yes it will, but I haven't seen any tutorials out there on how to do it, it is definitely possible though. One Signal has great documentation, so that will be the starting point. Next is understanding how to use third party frameworks in your buildozer project or however you're making your android .apk (I'm not familiar with android, so all I can do is outline the general steps for you)

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into making a background service for Android and the equivalent in ios.  I've given a rough breakdown on how to do this in this thread here https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/asojmg/examples_of_kivy_with_service_backend/

If you want to do this on linux\pc\macos I'm not sure about that but I'm sure there's similar background services for them too.